# Difference to remove left recursion for + and - or * or /?

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, left-recursion

To remove the left recursion

```
E->E+T|E-T|T
T->T*F|T/F|F
```

for + and *, I am sure it should be

```
E->TE'
E'->+TE'|(e) (e) is empty string
T->FT'
T'->*FT'|(e)
```

but for - or /, I am not sure how to remove left recursion, and I came up with the following one, is it right for - and /? Take an example, for plus, a+b = b+a, but for minus, a - b != b -a. So if we use the following right recursive, do we got the problem like a-b?

```
E->TE'
E'->+TE'|-TE'|(e) 
T->FT'
T'->*FT'|/FT'|(e)
```

Anyone know compiler explains to me?Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with `4-3`? Do you have an interpreter which interpretes this grammar? And it returns `-1` instead of `1`? The problem is probably not part of the grammar but of the interpreter. If so, then you should provide more information on the parser generator and the interpreter code.

Comment: I think you meant `T->T*F|T/F|F` (rather than `E/T`)

Comment: @rici yes, that's what I mean

Comment: @CoronA it's not about interpreter. I edited my question.

Comment: Not clear what your question is -- yes, the final grammar you show is the correct left-factorization of your initial grammar.  It can parse `+`, `-`, `*`, or `/`, just as the original grammar can, and recognizes the exact same language.  Obviously the parse tree for any given input will be different.

Comment: @David: The syntax tree may have the wrong associativity. But it is common that semantic analysis transforms the syntax tree, such that the correct associativity is achieved. And this is not a bug of the grammar, but of the semantic analsis/interpreter. Besides - correct the rule 2 as rici recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Left-recursion elimination allows an LL parser to correctly *recognize* a language, but the resulting parser does not produce the correct parse tree. In particular, it changes left-associative parses for operators such as `-` and `/` with right-associative parses.

In order to use the parse to actually interpret the parsed strings, you need to recover the correct parse tree, effectively by reversing the associativity for left-associative operators.

Alternatively, you could just use a bottom-up parser such as an LALR(1) parser generated by yacc/bison. Or you could write or adapt the operator-precedence algorithm (see "Shunting Yard").

If you're going to use the LL grammar in a recursive descent parser, the problem can be avoided since the recursive descent parser typically has an explicit loop instead of a recursion on the right-recursive production (in pseudo-code):

```
parse_term(): 
  f = parse_factor()
  while peek() is in ('*', '/'):
    op = token()
    f2 = parse_factor()
    f = apply_operator(op, f, f2)
  return f
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edited my question. It was confusing originally.

Comment: @David: I think my answer is still correct. Basically: Yes, it is a problem that the parse tree is not correct, but it can be dealt with; the answer attempts some suggestions as to how.