# Can operator associativity be defined in grammar besides left\right recursion

Tags: javascript, parsing, recursion, ecmascript-6, compiler-construction

[This article](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~fischer/cs536.s08/course.hold/html/NOTES/3.CFG.html) states that:

> To write a grammar that correctly expresses operator associativity:
>
> - For left associativity, use left recursion.
> - For right associativity,
>     use right recursion.

Am I right that left-recursive grammar is the only way to control associativity **on the grammar level**?

The other way which is mentioned here is Associativity and Precedence Declarations:

```
%left +
%left *
```

which as I understand are implemented on the actual parser level implementation.

However, LL parser cannot handle left-recursive grammar. So if I want to implement recursive-descent parser I'll need to somehow work around it in the implementation. Is it correct?

[Here](https://dannysu.com/2016/01/17/ecmascript1-parser/#grammar-with-left-recursion-eliminated) what an author implementing recursive-descent parser mentions:

> A recursive descent parser can parse grammar that doesn’t contain
>   left-recursion. However, the original ECMAScript grammar contains a
>   bunch of left-recursions that’ll be troublesome for a recursive
>   descent parser. Step one for beginning the parser is to convert the
>   grammar by eliminating left-recursion as I have done so here.
>
> It is interesting to note that the method for eliminating
>   left-recursion also messes with operator associativity, but I’ll deal
>   with it later.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for helping me learn the compiler!

Comment: It's not particularly difficult to handle left-associative operators in a recursive descent grammar; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33333514/1566221). That technique involves (a) rewriting the tail-recursion as a loop, and (b) rewriting the parse tree on the fly (although the rewrite is hardly noticeable). However, there is really no need: LR parser generators are easily available and do all the work for you, letting concentrate on more interesting things (like semantic processing of the parsed input: compiling, static analysis, pretty printing, or whatever.).

Comment: @rici, thanks, I'm trying to reverse-engineer TypeScript compiler that's why I'm focused on the top-down parsers